# How to make an iPhone app uncloseable?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to hand out iPhones as navigation/information devices to users at an event but users should only be able to see and use the event app and not close it or tamper with phone settings etc.

Is it possible to make an iPhone app not closable by the user and put it into a sort of 'presentation mode'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible by using guid access in your iphone,

Here is image how to set it.

[image]

So without your permission user cannot close apps.